# Sibling Elements with 100% Widths Aren't the Same Width?

Tags: css

This is driving me crazy. I've got a few sibling elements in the same form, *input fields* and divs (that contain input fields that need to stay on the same line), but when 100% width is applied to each, they aren't the same length; the divs are the same length as the other divs, and the independent inputs are the same as the other inputs. I've tried everything I can think of, and I can't figure out what's causing this behavior. It's messing-up my responsive styling, so I've come to a bit of a standstill...

If the width is 100%, and the elements are direct siblings of the same parent element, they SHOULD have equal widths, correct? In the screenshots below, the inputs inside the "bi-field-div" and "tri-field-div" elements are shorter, and the inputs that aren't inside a div are longer, even though the divs and inputs are both children of the same form element and are set to 100% (the one input you see in a class-less, id-less div still renders the same length as if there were no div at all-- I put it in there to test it.) I've tried extending the inputs within the divs by way of different percentages and margins and padding, but the div itself stays that shorter length, so the inputs within it just end up on different lines at a certain point; I've also fiddled with the positioning, displays, and everything else, and just can't get these stubborn things to stretch out equally!

I'll greatly appreciate any constructive advice you can give me.Thank you.

**HTML:**

```
        <form>
            <!-- pop-out text -->
                    <div class="div-form">
                        <p id="call-to-action">SIGN UP</p>
                        <p id="sub-text">Subrscribe to our newsletter</p>
                        <div id="bi-field-div">
                            <input type="text" class="form-field left-inline-field" placeholder="First Name">
                            <input type="text" class="form-field right-inline-field" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-field" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-field" placeholder="Phone" >
                        <div id="bi-field-div">
                            <input type="text" class="form-field left-inline-field" placeholder="State / Province">
                            <input type="text" class="form-field right-inline-field" placeholder="Zip">
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-field" placeholder="Company Name">
                        <input type="text" class="form-field" placeholder="How did you hear about us?">
                        <input type="text" class="form-field" placeholder="Company Name">
                        <div id="tri-field-div">
                            <input type="text" class="form-field tri-field" placeholder="Experience">
                            <input type="text" class="form-field tri-field" placeholder="Interests">
                            <input type="text" class="form-field tri-field" placeholder="Referral?">
                        </div>
                        <div class="signup-btn-div">
                            <button id="signup-btn">
                                SIGN UP
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="privacy-policy">
                            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
```

**CSS:**
[Form CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9QRa.png)

**What it looks like in browser:**
[Form in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3ibQ.png)

Comment: Can you please include the CSS in your post so we have a working [mcve]?

Comment: 46.6% + 46.6%... plus 0.5em left margin on left input.... is that supposed to equal 100%???

Comment: The CSS is in the screenshot linked to CSS: Form CSS in the post. You mean, add actual text for it in the post? If that's what you mean, I tried to, but it kept denying my post saying it was formatted incorrectly, so the screenshot seemed like my only option.

Comment: No, it doesn't equal 100%, but like I said, I've mixed around everything over and over to try to make this work, and no matter what the result is the same, whether the dimensions add up to 100 or not.